# How to Bulk Delete Spam Customers M2 2.3.5 p1

Tags: customer

Just moved over from M1 to M2 (hate it so slow)
But during setup I got 100's of spam emails with sex and porn in them.
In M1 you could filter on Porn then select and bulk delete no issue.

When i try in M2 it does nothing just sits there in console it checks up a lot CPC errors?
Is it easy to fix from admin backend?

See errors here top screen just loading customer, 2nd trying to delete
See [here](https://nextcloud.daddycloud.co.uk/s/6GMANAH64xfBESQ)